# Move content of beamer page upwards

Tags: beamer

Consider this TeX frame:

```
\begin{frame}{Risikoanalyse}
  \begin{figure}[t]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{Folie_Risikoanalyse-Vorgehen}
    \caption{Risikoanalyse im Entwicklungsprozess}
  \end{figure}
  Auswahl einiger Risiken für das Projekt:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item[1.] Risikoname 1
    \item[2.] Risikoname 2
    \item[3.] Risikoname 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

It looks like this:

[image: Page generated by code above]

As you can see, the bottom is a bit crowded, whereas at the top, due to how the picture is composed, there is a fair bit of space left. Other than that, I am already quite fine with it.

**I would like to shift everything *but the frame title* a little bit upwards, so that the spaces at top and bottom look less disproportionate to each other.**

**How?**

---

For completeness the environmental code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{datetime}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}
\ddmmyyyydate

\renewcommand{\figurename}{\footnotesize Abb. \thefigure}

\title[Projektname]{Arbeitsgruppe}
\subtitle{Projektname}
\author{Autor}
\institute{Institut}
\date{Datum}

\begin{document}
  [...]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Be careful: `\vspace{-1ex}` or similar.

Comment: As it's the first content, should probably be \vspace*{-1ex} or similar right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible solutions to this issue:

(1) I guess that the figure has some white space on the top. If that is the case, you can use crop and trim:

```
\includegraphics[trim=1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm, clip=true, scale=0.35]{figure}
```

(2) You can forcefully move something upwards by using vspace:

```
\vspace{-2cm}
```

places something 2cm higher.

For future posts it is nice to replace your image to which we don't have access by some kind of fake figure, e.g. import todonotes and use the missing-figure command later in your text:

```
\usepackage{todonotes} 
\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{Testing a long text string}
```

Comment: The figure does not have excess white space on the top. It does however have an alpha channel, so that all white is fully transparent. Second solution works like a charm (with "-.3cm"). Also thankful for the heads-up wrt. image dummies. Accepted and (lacking reputation, invisibly) upvoted.